# Lubuntu froze after running apt update

Tags: apt, lubuntu, laptop

I have a laptop from 2006, with Intel Pentium T2390, 2GB of RAM, and Lubuntu 18.04 LTS installed. But everytime i run `sudo apt update`, my laptop freezing after apt downloads the package list. Can you help me? Thanks

Output of `ls -la /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-stamp` -user535733

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 10 13:17 /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-stamp
```

Comment: It froze completely. And i'm holding the power button to reset.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `ls -la /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-stamp`

Comment: Your output shows that your apt update was successful at Dec 10 13:17. Therefore, your system is freezing *after* the apt update is complete. So it might be coincidence or related, but the apt update does not seem the direct cause of your problem. If it were, it wouldn't finish successfully. Next, review your logs in /var/log/syslog around the time of a freeze. Look for errors and warnings that occurred in the minute-or-so before the reboot.

Comment: If a system freezes; I'd not use the power-button unless absolutely necessary. Did you try switching to a text terminal (ctrl+alt+F4 for example), login & explore? or use SysRq keys to command the machine to safely shutdown/reboot etc (do a search for "magic sysrq" & wikipedia page will show; it's as good as any & at the top of a search listing). I'd likely explore your hardware, however hardware issues will be random freezes not something specific like you describe. Thus does SysRq commands work (ie. kernel is still operating), terminal show any clues? (waiting for network etc).

Comment: ps:  on some old laptops (eg. lenovo thinkpad sl510 (c2d-t6570, 2gb ram, i915)) I use to test Lubuntu with, the SysRq key isn't marked, but it works just the same; it just requires an extra key to be used (Fn + PrtScr plus other normal keys as per wikipedia.. this occurs with other laptops as well, but key can vary on device but some aren't marked like the thinkpad sl510)

Comment: 1. Sorry I left topic inactive. 2. I tried Alt+SysRq after freeze, doesn't work. 3. I also tried to switch to tty terminal, doesn't work too. I only see lines saying "Started PackageKit daemon"  while tailing syslog before laptop frozes. Or this line after i put my password in sudo prompt: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP